# How can I solve the CPLEX directory issues in R

Tags: r, cplex

The problem is that, am trying to install a package **cplexAPI** using the code

```
install.packages("cplexAPI")
```

```
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.5/include" -DNDEBUG -g -D_R_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -I"\cplex\include"         -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c cplexAPI.c -o cplexAPI.o
In file included from cplexAPI.h:26,
                 from cplexAPI.c:26:
cplexR.h:50:10: fatal error: ilcplex/cplex.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ilcplex/cplex.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.5/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: cplexAPI.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cplexAPI'
* removing 'C:/Users/ATM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cplexAPI'
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘cplexAPI’ had non-zero exit status
```

**What have done**

Have installed IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio

Version: 12.10.0.0

and tried to install the package again and  i experience the same issue

Kindly assist

Comment: Can you provide the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: ```sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5 tools_4.0.5   ```